# Unity Game WebGL hooking

Tags: unity-game-engine, hook, unity-webgl

Is it possible to hook unity game functions if game is built as webGL and is ran in the web browser? I no need solution to do it, I just want avoid possible cheaters.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use `unityInstance.SendMessage('MyGameObject', 'MyFunction', 'MyString');` construction.

Here you can search more information https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html